# java-jnativehook doesn't work is it caused by the antivirus?

Tags: java, logging, key

I need to listen a key (F5) when my program is not focused, I found the JNativeHook library which was working well on Linux.
But now i try my program on Windows and i got this error:
juil. 12, 2014 3:46:41 PM org.jnativehook
GRAVE: hook_thread_proc [68]: SetWindowsHookEx() failed! (0X7E)

And I just can't read me keyboard with JNativeHook.
What is the problem ? Is it a problem with my antivirus or is it a problem with my Windows or with my code ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The SetWindowsHookEx() function seems to be returning 126 (0x7E) ERROR_MOD_NOT_FOUND.  I have never seen that error returned so you have either discovered a bug in the code or it is something with your system (like antivirus).  AFAIK, the library itself has not been flagged as a virus but I am not sure if you have some kind of restriction on the SetWindowsHookEx function.

What version of the library are you using?  Can you produce all of the console output?  If you can reliably reproduce the issue, please open a [bug report](https://code.google.com/p/jnativehook/).

**Update:** It could be related to [issue #43](https://code.google.com/p/jnativehook/issues/detail?id=43) where too many hooks are currently installed on the system.  This is the last major known issue in the library; in short, Microsoft decided to modify the SetWindowsHookEx API in a number of ways starting with Vista and didn't provide a way to work around the issue.  I can't even duplicate the problem on my end to debug the issue.  I would suggest reading though the entire bug report and see if you can shed any light on exactly what is happening and how to reproduce it.

Comment: Hello, I have seen this issue and I think it is caused by this issue, because the output is the same.
I have found an other way to read my key, I use this C++ function (from windows.h): GetAsyncKeyState, I build a simple DLL that I call in an infinity loop (in a thread) to see if the key is pressed.
I know it is not the best way, but it is working so it will be enough untill JNativeHook can fix the bug :)

Comment: Does the bug happen every time for you?  I have been unable to reproduce the bug on any of my machines making it difficult to debug.

Comment: Yes it happens everytime i tried on my machine with Windows 7

Comment: Please send me an email so I can send you some test code to try and let me know What anti-virus are you using.

Comment: I am in holiday actually so I could not test it beurre august :/

Comment: My antivirus is very bad it is McAfee :/